# Setting the global value of an environment variable after login

Tags: environment-variables

Can I set the global value of an environment variable after having logged in?  That is achieve the effect of having set it in `~/.profile`.

Comment: What variable do you want to set?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can however any executable that are launch before will not get the new value.

Just use :

```
export TMOUT=100
export FOO=bar
```

If you are in text session (putty/ssh) this is probably OK, if you are in a GUI session, this may cause problems if variable to be set are use by GUI programs.